# How to Delete multiple selected records on Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm tasked with making a form on Access to delete multiple selected records without a user control and a delete query.

The user selects (by highlighting) the records with the record selector. I need to add VBA code to a delete button that will delete all the selected records. When I do that only the first record is deleted.

How do I make the highlighted records the active records and delete them all at once? I assume I need a loop of some sort.

I looked through some suggested links and this is what I have:

```
intHeight = Me.Form.SelHeight
intTop = Me.Form.SelTop

Dim N As Integer
With Me.Form.RecordsetClone
    If .RecordCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing saved, Delete canceled.", , "Remove Test Error"
    Else
        Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete records?", vbYesNo,   "Duplicate?", 0, 0)
        If Response = vbYes Then
            MsgBox (intHeight)
            For N = 1 To intHeight
                .AbsolutePosition = intTop - 1
                .MoveFirst
                sql = "DELETE FROM [Feb Fleet] Where [ID]=&Me.ID.Value"
                CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
                Me.Form.Requery
            Next
        End If
    End If
End With
```

The code goes through but nothing is deleted. When I check the intHeight value, I get 0. I'm not sure if the .SelTop method works in my code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried so far by providing some code.

Comment: User selects consecutive records? Have to loop through the set of selected records and run delete code. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1669535. It gets a little complicated.

Comment: Another reference http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=45046

Comment: That button is already there - on the keyboard: `Delete`.

Comment: @Gustav, good point. I use custom delete because I have to manage deletion of related records. In case a user even thinks to use key Delete, I catch and cancel the key Delete event and invoke MsgBox to user to use the custom button. Button also allows mouse click for delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in Access is that the selection gets lost when the focus moves to the button. I solved the problem by placing a sub-form in datasheet view on the main form. The main form has either no data source or is bound to a parent record.

Sub-form controls have an `Exit` event. During this event, the sub-form selection is still valid. Therefore I use this event to store the selection

```vb
Dim top As Long, height As Long

'Exit event of the sub-form control
Private Sub frmSelect_Products_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    top = frmSelect_Products.Form.SelTop
    height = frmSelect_Products.Form.SelHeight
End Sub
```

In the delete event handler you can do something like this (just made some test outputs without actually deleting). Also you will have to adapt some names.

```vb
Dim N As Long, sql As String

'Restore the selection so the user can see it during the delete dialog.
frmSelect_Products.Form.SelHeight = height

'Test
MsgBox "top = " & top & ",    height = " & height

With frmSelect_Products.Form.RecordsetClone
    For N = top + height - 1 To top Step -1
        .AbsolutePosition = N - 1 'Zero-based
        sql = "DELETE FROM [Feb Fleet] Where [ID]=" & .Fields!ProductID
        MsgBox sql
        'CurrentDb.Execute sql
    Next
End With
Me.Form.Requery
```

Your code moves to the first selected item with `.AbsolutePosition = intTop - 1` and then moves to the first record with `.MoveFirst`, ignoring the position previously set through `AbsolutePosition`. I.e., the position given by the loop variable `N` is completely ignored.